# Mobile friendly ways to do a "Candle flame" animation

Tags: actionscript, mobile-website, css-animations

I haven't tried posting here before so I hope that I am doing it right.

Some years ago I bought this candle flame Flash based animation:
http://activeden.net/item/candle-flame-animation-v3/discussion/42205

Anyways, that is done in Flash using Action Script and so I am looking for an alternative that looks just as good but works on mobile devices.

I have tried creating small looped movie segments of the animation, gif's and a seris of jpgs using a sprite.
But none of the above really works that well and so I am looking for an alternative.

Could something like this be done in html, css3, javascript? And is there a library/framework out there that could help me build it?

I tried to convert the file via Google Swiffy once, and the end result actually looked surprisingly close to the original, but in terms of performance I was able to crash the browser on my phone everytime I tried seeing the animation.

Can Google Swiffy's code be optimized easily?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a particle system? There are some javascript libraries out there, for instance:

https://github.com/gamealchemist/JSparkle

The demos don't include a 'candle' effect but it shouldn't be that hard to achieve.